# How to extract one file from a specific directory of a zip file

Tags: command-line, zip

I got a zip file like this:

```
zipfile.zip  
          |______ -JWQYBCVAQA=

                    |_______ text.txt
                             othergarbage.jpg
                             othergarbage.deb
                             othergarbage.whatever
```

I only need to extract text.txt

i tryed: `unzip Externo.zip -x '/-JWQYBCVAQA=/behavior_packs' '/-JWQYBCVAQA=/db' '/-JWQYBCVAQA=/resource_packs' '/-JWQYBCVAQA=/level.dat' '/-JWQYBCVAQA=/level.dat.old' '/-JWQYBCVAQA=/world_icon.jpeg'`

But it outputs that there is no files with those names

I don't know how to do this , any help is apreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a leading slash, and just give the path to the file as the second argument:

```
unzip zipfile.zip -JWQYBCVAQA=/test.txt
```

You can also use wildcards:

```
unzip zipfile.zip '*/test.txt'
```

For files/directories whose names start with `-d` or `-x` (which are the options allowed after the zip filename), to escape them you can prefix with `\\` (`\` for `unzip` itself, and the extra escape for the shell) or `'\'`.

Comment: @Rinzwind `unzip` is one distinctly non-Unixy command, so I think it should work. (If it doesn't, the wildcard option should still work for OP's structure.)

Comment: Thanks @Rinzwind :)

Comment: Think you can escape hyphens `unzip zipfile \\-JWQYBCVAQA=/test.txt`

Comment: short example: `touch -- -d -x; zip a ./!(a.zip); unzip a \\-d \\-x -d b` will create the files `-d`,`-x` in an archive a.zip and extract them to directory `b`

Comment: @bac0n ah, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To extract to a specific directory, say "mydir", you would use:

```
unzip \
    -o `# overwrite`\
    -j zipfile.zip \
        -JWQYBCVAQA=/{text.txt,othergarbage.jpg} \
    -d mydir
```

For all of the files in "-JWQYBCVAQA=" just use `-JWQYBCVAQA=/*`